# Parsing DateTime values renders diferent dates for different time zones - JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure, parsing, datetime

Recently I migrated one of my ASP.NET MVC application into Azure cloud. 
One of the issues I've been facing after migration is that the DateTime values are rendering different values for different time zones while being parsed in a JS file.

**NOTE : DateTime values are being stored with correct values in DB (SQL Server) irrespective of DB location. Plus while retrieving these values from DB in C# class also fetches accurate values.**

**Hence it's definitely a JS parsing/rendering issue.**

Following is my JS file code:-

```
function Dateformat(date) {
    var d = new Date(parseInt(date.slice(6, -2)));
    var realdate = '' + (1 + d.getMonth()) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear().toString();
    return realdate;

}
```

Let's consider a example where a datetime value fetched is, let's say :

```
2017-07-10 05:37:16.700
```

Now this DateTime value is a correct value being fetched in C# file accurately.
So in normal scenario it should have been rendered the same value for all time zones. But that's not the case.

Now when I set my local machine to

```
(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
```

timezone (which is my default), debugging the JS through console gives me the following (which is a correct value)  :

[image]]

But when I set my timezone to, let's say :

```
 (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
```

timezone , debugging the JS through console gives me the following (which is an  incorrect value)  :

[image]

**Instead of  displaying 2017-07-10,  it displays  2017-07-09 in the UI.**

So all the datetime values are displayed as one date previous to the actual date in the UI.

Even users from US who save date, on say Nov 6th, see a one date previous to actual vale, in this case Nov 5th. But this same date get's accurately displayed as Nov 6th in UTC+05:30 time zone (hence users in this time zone see correct values while users from previous timezone see incorrect one's).

**NOTE: Initally before migration, while my application was still on-prem, the same JS code rendered correct datetime values irrespective of any time-zone.**

This JS method is being invoked from both CSHTML files and the JS files.
For example :

```
<td class="${setClass(RowNumber)}">${Dateformat(SubmitDate)}</td>
```

---

**How do I save DateTime values in DB?**

I'm using **DateTime.Now** in my C# code file while saving date values in DB.
So whenever a users enters some data, the date will be saved based on his time zone. Now while displaying that date, it should show the same date value for all the users worldwide.

---

How can I fix this issue?
Is this releted to the 'Region' value we set for the Resource Groups in Azure portal while configuring the application in Azure?

Comment: `new Date(value)` ... value is *integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 **UTC*** - so, are you sending UTC?

Comment: you do realise, changing your time zone from +5:30 to -8:00 means that a lot of the time you will get the previous day? because, well, that's how timezones work ... `new Date(1499644800000)` is `10 July 2017 0:00:00 UTC` .... which is 5:30am on the same day in +5:30 ... or 16:00 the previous day in -8:00 ... perhaps you want to use `getUTC[Day|Month|Fullyear]` functions instead

Comment: Since there is no guarantee that the Client has their System Time correct, you should just show them the timezone and use your Server Time, unless you want to add a disclaimer regarding incorrect times.

Comment: As I mentioned in my description the datetime being fetched from DB is 2017-07-10. So it should show the same date to all the users worldwide.

Comment: Storing `DateTimeOffset`s instead of `DateTime` is a good idea. Otherwise you have to make an assumption about the timezone of the stored datetimes.

Comment: @Jaromanda X Can you show some sample code based on my JS code regarding using getUTC?

Comment: so ... var realdate = '' + (1 + d.get**UTC**Month()) + '/' + d.get**UTC**Date() + '/' + d.get**UTC**FullYear().toString(); ?

Comment: @Jaromanda X Adding UTC indeed helped me getting consistent dates. Can you add this solutioin as an answer to this question so that I can mark it as an accepted anser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per **@Jaromanda X**'s solution in the comment, I'm using the UTC date format to solve this issue.

Here's my updated solution :

```
function Dateformat(date) {
    var d = new Date(parseInt(date.slice(6, -2)));
    var realdate = '' + (1 + d.getUTCMonth()) + '/' + d.getUTCDate() + '/' + d.getUTCFullYear().toString();
    return realdate;
}
```